# dcast of data table does not return expect result

Tags: r, data.table

With the following data.table:

```
dt_cpu_[2000:2010,]
                    tim   source type_instance       val
 1: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3        system     29471
 2: 2016-08-22 05:35:46.788  DBNode1         steal         0
 3: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3         steal         0
 4: 2016-08-22 05:35:46.788  DBNode1          nice    617733
 5: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3          wait       452
 6: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3          idle 401793528
 7: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3         steal         0
 8: 2016-08-22 05:16:02.336  DBNode3       softirq         0
 9: 2016-08-22 05:16:02.336  DBNode3         steal         0
 10: 2016-08-22 05:36:28.926 DNSFront          wait    211213
 11: 2016-08-22 05:36:28.926 DNSFront          nice    661508
```

With the following types:

```
  str(dt_cpu_)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10576673 obs. of  4 variables:
$ tim          : POSIXct, format: "2016-08-22 05:06:48.901" 
$ source       : chr  "DNSBack" "DBNode3" "DNSBack" "DBNode2" ...
$ type_instance: chr  "softirq" "user" "system" "user" ...
$ val          : num  0 99732 829061 171631 15111 ...
```

I use the following code to cast the data.table:

```
dt_cpu_cast <- dcast.data.table(dt_cpu_[2000:2010,], tim + source ~ type_instance,  drop = TRUE, value.var="val")
```

I would expect to get as output something like:

```
                       tim   source system   steal  nice   wait    idle   softirq
 1: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3  29471  0     NA     452   401793528  NA
 1: 2016-08-22 05:35:46.788  DBNode1  NA     0     617733 NA    NA         NA
```

But instead I get the following:

```
                     tim   source    idle  nice  softirq steal system wait
1: 2016-08-22 05:16:02.336  DBNode3    0    0       1     1      0    0
2: 2016-08-22 05:16:12.336  DBNode3    1    0       0     2      1    1
3: 2016-08-22 05:35:46.788  DBNode1    0    1       0     1      0    0
4: 2016-08-22 05:36:28.926 DNSFront    0    1       0     0      0    1
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can you provide me some guidance?

Comment: You have duplicates (so it can't just take the value, as there are more than one, and it defaults to `length` instead). Try `dcast(unique(dt), ...)`.

Comment: And I guess grouping on a float/POSIXct might not be a great approach, since who knows whether two times differing in microseconds will or won't be deemed equal for grouping purposes? Safer/better to use `IDateTime`, probably.

Comment: Thanks Eddi and Frank. Your suggestions allowed me to solve this issue. In this particular case, using the `fun.aggregate = sum` solves the problem.